# How to setup "enabled protocol" for IIS application using intallshield installation

Tags: iis, protocols, installshield

I'm trying to create an MSI for a .NET WCF web service in IIS 7.5. The service is going to use TCP instead of HTTP for a protocol.

In order to use TCP, I have to add the text ",net.tcp" to the "Enabled Protocols" setting of the application's virtual directory (Under "Advanced Settings..." in the IIS managment console).

Is there any way to configure the "Enabled Protocols" for a virtual directory in IIS 2012? At the moment, I don't see a way to configure this setting

Comment: How is setup development off topic?

Answer (score 1):

I've frequently observed that with each new release of IIS there will be a setting or two that InstallShield is lacking.  After a release or two they typically catch up.  In the meantime I use InstallShield to do most of the IIS configuration and then use the IIS provided "appcmd.exe"  utility in a custom action to patch the rest.